Is the derivative of a dot product a covector?
I'm having a hard time understanding Eq. 69 in "The Matrix Cookbook" (p. 10). [1]
[1] https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf
It states an identity:
$$ \dfrac{\partial\mathbf{x}^\top \mathbf{a}}{\partial \mathbf{x}} =
 \dfrac{\partial\mathbf{a}^\top \mathbf{x}}{\partial \mathbf{x}}=
  \mathbf{a} $$
If I'm understanding the notation, then if $f(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{x}^\top \mathbf{a} $, then this would say
$ \frac{d}{d \mathbf{x}} f(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{a} $.
However, to my understanding, the total derivative of a map $ f: \mathbf{R}^n \to \mathbf{R} $ is a covector. According to Wikipedia [2], "the gradient ∇ f and the derivative d f are expressed as a column and row vector, respectively."
[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient#Relationship_with_total_derivative
Would it be more technically accurate to say that
$ \frac{d}{d \mathbf{x}} f(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{a}^\top $?

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ be the map $f(\textbf{x})= \textbf{a}^T\textbf{x}$. Now we calculate the gradient.
$$\nabla f = \left[\frac{df}{dx^1},\dots, \frac{df}{dx^n}\right]^T=\left[a_1,\dots,a_n\right]^T=\textbf{a}$$
it's just a vector at every point. Then the total derivative is a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$Df(\textbf{x})=\nabla f \cdot \textbf{x}$$

The total derivative is not always a co-vector. It's just a linear transformation between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ but in this case $m=1$.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

They define $a$ as a "column-vector" earlier in the book and I guess $x$ as well. Then $a^\intercal x= x^\intercal a$ because it's the same real number. The Fréchet derivative $D_x(a^\intercal x)=a^\intercal$. Using the standard inner product we can introduce a corresponding gradient vector which they denote as $\frac{d}{dx}f$ and is indeed $a$ in this case.
